# Redirect page in c# mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have link

```
http://localhost:3163/PaymentOrder?AgentCode=&InvoiceNo=&AgentName=&FromDate=&fromDate=12%2F11%2F2013&FromDate=12%2F11%2F2013+9%3A08%3A01+SA&toDate=12%2F11%2F2013
```

after click button "Delete" the page should be redirect to "Index"

```
        return RedirectToAction("Index","PaymentOrder");
```

But i want keep link same as first, i don't know what method, please help me. thanks

I can fix it, i save session in

```
public ActionResult Index{
  Session["LastPage"] = Request.Url.ToString();
}
```

after I'm

`return Redirect(Session["LastPage"] as String);`

Comment: I can fix it, i save session in 'public ActionResult Index{Session["LastPage"] = Request.Url.ToString();}' after I'm

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the query strings to the third parameter of `RedirecToAction`

```
return RedirectToAction("Index","PaymentOrder", new { fromDate = model.FromDate });
```

Or pass the entire model as well, that contains the properties similar to your query strings

```
return RedirectToAction("Index","PaymentOrder", new { paymentModel = model });
```

Answer (score 2):

As your query string is quite long, it would probably be better to write an extension method and use that instead, to keep your controllers thin.  I haven't tested this, but something like this should work:

```
public static RouteValueDictionary ToRouteDictionary(this NameValueCollection nameValues)
{
    if (nameValues == null || nameValues.HasKeys() == false)
        return new RouteValueDictionary();

    var routeValues = new RouteValueDictionary();

    foreach (var key in nameValues.AllKeys)
        routeValues.Add(key, nameValues[key]);

    return routeValues;
}
```

Then in your controller:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index","PaymentOrder", Request.QueryString.ToRouteDictionary());
```

Answer (score 1):

Just don't redirect but return the view, the URL will remain the same.